# Do rel='next' & rel='prev' stop all pagination from being indexed but the first?

Tags: duplicate-content, pagination

On an ecommerce website the category page of a type of product has pagination.
A view all system isn't used because the page speed would be too high.
The HTML `rel='next'` & `rel='prev'` links are used.

Upon a site: search, the sequential pages are indexed.

There is also organic traffic managing to land on these pages from Google.

Should the `rel='next'` & `rel='prev'` stop all the pages from being indexed but the first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the `rel="prev"` and `rel="next"` won't stop all the pages but the first being indexed, and **that is exactly what you want it to do**.

The rel tags are instead used to indicate to Google that these set of pages are connected in a 'paginated' setup. After finding those tags on a page, Google will work its magic with regards to crawling, indexing and ranking those pages. Afterwards, it might, or might not, decide to crawl those pages (at a certain rate) and/or keep those pages in the index and/or let those pages rank.

Sources:

- https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1663744?hl=en
- https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2011/09/pagination-with-relnext-and-relprev.html